# Azure Search - Query Collection of GeographyPoint

Tags: odata, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am trying to query a collection GeographyPoint within a given range from my index. I am using Azure Search.

My index contains a list of GeographyPoint

```
public class Parent
{
     public List<Child> Coordinates {get; set;}
}


public class Child
{ 
     public GeographyPoint Coordinates { get; set; }
}
```

I know if there was a single property named location on the index you could query it with something like:

> $filter=geo.distance(location, geography'POINT(-82.51571 31.89063)') le 0.1524

but how do you query a collection? I've tried using the any/all filters like:

> $filter=geo.distance(IndexedCompany/Offices/any(c: c/PhysicalAddress/Coordinates), geography'POINT(-82.51571 31.89063)') le 0.1524

but I get the error: *"Invalid expression: The Any/All query expression must evaluate to a single boolean value.\r\nParameter name: $filter"*

Any  help on how to query a collection of GeographyPoint would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in how you've constructed your filter. Let's break it down using types, since that's the easiest way to see where things went wrong.

`$filter=geo.distance(IndexedCompany/Offices/any(c: c/PhysicalAddress/Coordinates), geography'POINT(-82.51571 31.89063)') le 0.1524`

Starting from the outside in, the top-most expression in a filter must be Boolean, and that checks out here because you're comparing `geo.distance` (which returns `Edm.Double`) with a literal distance using `le`. So that part is fine.

Next, let's look at `geo.distance`. It takes two points of type `Edm.GeographyPoint` and returns an `Edm.Double`. The second parameter is a literal point, so that's fine, but the first parameter is not. Let's look at that next.

The first parameter to `geo.distance` here is the expression `IndexedCompany/Offices/any(c: c/PhysicalAddress/Coordinates)`. Although it's really an operator, you can think of `any` as a kind of function that returns a Boolean. That would be a problem, because `geo.distance` is expecting a point, not a Boolean. That's our first clue to what's wrong here, but it doesn't actually explain the error message you're seeing. Let's dig further to understand that.

Assume for the moment that the expression `IndexedCompany/Offices/any(c: c/PhysicalAddress/Coordinates)` was your entire filter. You'd still get the same error message: `"Invalid expression: The Any/All query expression must evaluate to a single boolean value."` To see why, consider what `any` and `all` expect in terms of types. Each one iterates over a collection of some type, applying a predicate in the form of a lambda expression to each element. That lambda expression in this case is `c/PhysicalAddress/Coordinates`, which (I'm assuming) is an `Edm.GeographyPoint`, not a Boolean.

Taking a step back, it helps to think about the cardinalities involved here. Each document contains a company, which has many offices, which each has a geo-point location. I'm assuming the goal is to match the whole document in case any of those co-ordinates match the filter. In that case, you really just need to re-order the parts of your query so that the types and cardinalities line up:

`$filter=IndexedCompany/Offices/any(office: geo.distance(office/PhysicalAddress/Coordinates, geography'POINT(-82.51571 31.89063)') le 0.1524)`

The filter is still a Boolean expression because that's the type of `any`. The lambda passed to `any` takes an Office, applies `geo.distance` to its geo-location, and compares the distance to the desired value. Now everything type checks and the iteration is happening the right place.

**Example: search=***

```
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "id": "myid1",
        "pts": [
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 0, 0 ],
                "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } }
            },
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 0, 1 ],
                "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "id": "myid2",
        "pts": [
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 0, 10 ],
                "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } }
            },
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 0, 11 ],
                "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**Example $filter=pts/any(pt: geo.distance(pt, geography'POINT(0 2)') le 111.3192394008)**

```
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 1,
        "id": "myid1",
        "pts": [
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 0, 0 ],
                "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } }
            },
            {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ 0, 1 ],
                "crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "EPSG:4326" } }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: great answer an explanation.  Really should be accepted.