# Store edm.GeographyPointCollection in Azure Search using C#

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have successfully created and populated a location field in Azure Search ... but cannot get the correct serializer / c# type for edm.GeographyPointCollection

```cs
using Azure.Core.Serialization;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes.Models;
using Microsoft.Spatial;
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
...
[JsonConverter(typeof(MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter))]
[JsonPropertyName("location")]
[SimpleField(IsFilterable = true, IsSortable = true)]
public GeographyPoint? Location { get; set; }

?????
public List<GeographyPoint> ?????? Locations { get; set; }
...
```

The converter [appears](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/pull/24520/files) to have been fixed in October 2021, but the [version available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Core.Spatial) was published in June 2021

- What C# type should I use to map to edm.GeographyPointCollection ([Microsoft learn does not say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/supported-data-types#edm-data-types-used-in-azure-cognitive-search-indexes-and-documents))?
- How do I make this work with the JsonConverter?
- The [beta release](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Core.Spatial/1.2.0-beta.1) only has a writer for GeographyPoint ... this is not the same version as [the current code in github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/core/Microsoft.Azure.Core.Spatial/src/Serialization/MicrosoftSpatialGeoJsonConverter.cs)

The answer at [Azure Search - Query Collection of GeographyPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602642/azure-search-query-collection-of-geographypoint) uses a workaround by having a property with a child collection of GeographyPoint. How do I map to the GeographyPointCollection directly, or is the workaround the only viable way to do this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59602642/azure-search-query-collection-of-geographypoint though appears to use complex types?